# How to get selected option with beautifulsoup and Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get the data from a combobox using beautifulsoup, but when using my code I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

DATA:

```
<select name="sexo" style="width: 140px; display: none;" id="sexo" class="clasecombo_valid" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">
<option selected="" value="">[SELECCIONAR]</option>
<option value="M" selected="">Masculino</option>  <<<<SELECTED ITEM
<option value="F">Femenino</option>
</select>
```

My code:

```
sexo = BeautifulSoup(login_request.text, 'lxml').find('input', {'name': 'sexo'}).get('value')
print(sexo)
```

How can i get only the selected value?

Comment: Having no attribute suggests that BS has not found the intended object at all. Are you sure you should be finding "input" and not finding "select"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element you want to search for is `select`, not `input`. And if you want the selected value, you have to search within that for the `option` with the `selected` attribute.

You can combine these into a single call using a selector.

```
sexo = BeautifulSoup(login_request.text, 'lxml').select('select[name=sexo] option[selected]')[0].value
```

This probably isn't going to be very useful, since the selected value is the empty value that goes with the `[SELECCIONAR]` prompt. You're not getting anything that a user has selected.

Comment: I get "None" when print, sorry Im newbie